# Why aren't comments protected from accidentally hitting Back in your browser?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Sometimes I accidentally hit the "back" button on the side of my mouse when returning my hand to the mouse from the keyboard when entering a comment. Typically pages will popup a "stay on this page" confirmation which saves me most of the time.

However, the comment field does not protect hitting "back". Your comment is simply discarded.

Comment: hitting the enter/return key will post a comment so your back button won't be an issue

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was assuming that the OP is using the mouse to click the add comment button after typing a comment, which results in an accidental back button use that the enter key would prevent. though i suppose this could be an overzealous assumption.

Comment: @Ryathal: Ah, yes, good point. If the OP used the enter key instead of the mouse he'd wouldn't bump the extra 'back' button on it either. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I usually put my hand on the mouse to use the scroll wheel and look over it the question or answers before I post the comment. I usually use Enter to post but since many web pages aren't very keyboard friendly I do use the button sometimes out of habit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a way to scroll the page when the caret is flashing in a multiline input field? You have to use the mouse, right?

Comment: @doug65536: there are [official keyboard shortcuts](http://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts); not sure if they'd help for long posts, but you can go `TAB` and `u` and `k` & `j` to navigate between question and answers on the page, then `Shift`-`TAB` to go back to your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because comments are second-class citizens.

They are discardable, as the value of the site is in the questions and the answers.

As such, comments are not offered the same kinds of protections. When you delete them, they are gone forever (questions and answers can be undeleted). There is no edit history for comments, let alone the ability to roll back edits. And there is no unload protection for them either.

Try not to put anything too valuable in them. :-)